# I tried to run my Spring-boot application but alway failed by the issue "Failed to retrieve application beans snapshot: /n:application=*"

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to run my application file in a Springboot application way.
But the application always stuck in the very beginning step as the screenshot attached.

When I checked the event log, the error message is :
`Failed to retrieve application beans snapshot: :application=*`

I tried to adjust my application.yml but not work at all